# UIAlertController causes RowAnimation of a UITableViewCell-Deletion not to be called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, uialertcontroller

I try to integrate an alert before the user deletes information.
Without animation the row deletion was animated and worked fine. But in the UIAlertAction handler the animation no longer works:

```
  UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                   message:@"Are you sure you want to delete the Inforamtion?"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* deleteAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                              // Find the cell taped Item using the position  of the sender as located at relative to the tableview
                                                              CGPoint buttonPosition = [deleteTapped convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
                                                              NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

                                                              // Update the data model
                                                              [self.checkout.paymentMethods removeObjectAtIndex:(indexPath.row -1)];

                                                              // Delete the row from the tableview
                                                              [self.tableView beginUpdates];
                                                              [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimationFade)];
                                                              [self.tableView endUpdates];


                                                          }];

    [alert addAction:deleteAction];

    UIAlertAction* keepAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Keep" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                         }];



 [alert addAction:keepAction];

 [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any suggestion how to make the animation work again?

Answer (score 0):

i think that begin and endUpdate call is causing problem. Please rome them it should work.

Use this way:

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                   message:@"Are you sure you want to delete the Inforamtion?"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* deleteAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                              // Find the cell taped Item using the position  of the sender as located at relative to the tableview
                                                              CGPoint buttonPosition = [deleteTapped convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
                                                              NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

                                                              // Update the data model
                                                              [self.checkout.paymentMethods removeObjectAtIndex:(indexPath.row -1)];

                                                              // Delete the row from the tableview
                                                              [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


                                                          }];

    [alert addAction:deleteAction];

    UIAlertAction* keepAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Keep" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                         }];



 [alert addAction:keepAction];
```

Comment: I tried it and this is not what causes the problem. After you tap delete the tableview updates and the cell is gone without an animation.